# Splitting a list by alternating elements

Tags: f#

I'm trying to split an F# list into two by taking alternate elements. Here's my attempt:

```
let split l =  
    let rec loop l isEven result1 result2 =  
        match l with  
        | [] -> result1 result2  
        | [head::tail] when isEven -> loop tail (not isEven) head::result1 result2  
        | [head::tail] -> loop tail (not isEven) result1 head::result2  
    loop l false [] []
```

That gives me an error:

```
Program.fs(5,39): error FS0001: Type mismatch. Expecting a  
    'a    
but given a  
    'b -> 'a list      
The resulting type would be infinite when unifying ''a' and ''b -> 'a list'
```

I don't see how it can be infinite, and I don't understand why it thinks I'm giving it a function from 'b to 'a list.  Could somebody tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a fixed version:

```
let rec loop l isEven result1 result2 =
    match l with
    | [] ->
        result1, result2
    | head :: tail when isEven ->
        loop tail (not isEven) (head :: result1) result2
    | head :: tail ->
        loop tail (not isEven) result1 (head :: result2)
```

- In the first case (`[]`), I added a comma since the the `loop` function needs to return the values as a tuple. Without the comma, you're basically treating `result1` like a function and applying `result2` to it.
- The empty list pattern was correct (`[]`) but in the other cases, you don't use the brackets -- just the cons (`::`) pattern.
- You needed to enclose the `head :: result` in parenthesis, otherwise F# reads the code as if you wrote this: `(loop tail (not isEven) head) :: (result1 result2)`.

Oh, and if you want the lists you're returning to be in the same order as the original list, you need to use List.rev when you return the lists, like this:

```
match l with
| [] ->
    List.rev result1, List.rev result2
```

Finally, here's a slightly simplified version of your function -- you don't really need the `isEven` parameter to make the function work. Instead, you just try to keep the lists the same length:

```
let rec loop (result1, result2) l =
    match l with
    | [] ->
        List.rev result1, List.rev result2
    | hd :: tl ->
        if List.length result1 = List.length result2 then
            loop (hd :: result1, result2) tl
        else
            loop (result1, hd :: result2) tl
```

Comment: `List.length` is O(N) – _not_ something to put in a loop.

Comment: So it is. For some reason, I thought the F# implementation stored the length of the list in a private field for fast access. Well, since that's the not case -- @gradbot's solution will be faster.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  As you can tell, I'm still very new to F#!

Answer (score 6):

Jack did a good job of explaining what's wrong.  Here's an alternate solution that matches two elements at a time.  F#'s [pattern matching documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd547125.aspx) has a lot of great examples.

```
let split list = 
    let rec split odd even list =
        match list with
        | a::b::tail -> split (a::odd) (b::even) tail
        | a::tail -> split (a::odd) even tail
        | [] -> List.rev odd, List.rev even

    split [] [] list
```

Example output.

```
printfn "%A" (split [1 .. 10])
System.Console.ReadLine() |> ignore

([1; 3; 5; 7; 9], [2; 4; 6; 8; 10])
```

Comment: Thanks. I've given Jack the tick for the correct solution because the explanation of where I went wrong was the main thing I needed, but your solution is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is not tail recursive but is very comprehensible:

```
let prepend2 (x, y) (xs, ys) = x::xs, y::ys

let rec split = function
  | [] | [_] as xs -> xs, []
  | x0::x1::xs -> prepend2 (x0, x1) (split xs)
```

Comment: -1: `| [] | [_] -> []` will lose the last element if the list has odd number of elements.